# linerange in listinput firstnumber conflicts with stepnumber

Tags: listings, numbering

If I create a code include as follows:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange=39-46, firstnumber=39]{./Matlab/script.m}
```

And set the stepnumber to 5 in the lstset:

```
\lstset{...,stepnumber = 5, ...}
```

Line 40, 45 and 39 are numbered but I only want to number line 1, 5, 10 etc. So in this example 39 should not be displayed.
Firstnumber=auto starts not at the true line number.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works like requested:

```
\documentclass{article}% at line 39
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{stepnumber=5}
\lstinputlisting[
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  linerange=39-46,
  firstnumber=39,
  numbers=left,
]{test.tex}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Only lines numbers `40` and `45` are shown.

Or if the numbering should start at 1 (`firstnumber=1`) and the first line should also be numbered (`numberfirstline`):

```
\documentclass{article}% at line 39
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\lstset{stepnumber=5,numberfirstline}
\lstinputlisting[
  language={[LaTeX]TeX},
  linerange=39-46,
  firstnumber=1,
  numbers=left,
]{test.tex}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Version of package `listings` is 2007/02/22 v1.4.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, it turned out that in my preamble I declared:

    numberfirstline = true

in the lstset option. This should be set to false for this specific list inclusion. However, it is mandatory to force displaying a 1 for the first line number as it is not modulo 5.